# How to find textual differences between revisions on Wikipedia pages with mwclient?

Tags: python, wikipedia-api, mwclient

I'm trying to find the textual differences between two revisions of a given Wikipedia page using mwclient. I have the following code:

```
import mwclient
import difflib

site = mwclient.Site('en.wikipedia.org')
page = site.pages['Bowdoin College']
texts = [rev for rev in page.revisions(prop='content')]
if not (texts[-1][u'*'] == texts[0][u'*']):
      ##show me the differences between the pages
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear weather you want a `difflib`-generated diff or a mediawiki-generated diff using `mwclient`.

In the first case, you have two strings (the text of two revisions) and you want to get the diff using [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.unified_diff):

```
...
t1 = texts[-1][u'*']
t2 = texts[0][u'*']
print('\n'.join(difflib.unified_diff(t1.splitlines(), t2.splitlines())))
```

(difflib can also generate an HTML diff, refer to the documentation for more info.)

But if you want the MediaWiki-generated HTML diff using `mwclient` you'll need revision `ids`:

```
# TODO: Loading all revisions is slow,
# try to load only as many as required.
revisions = list(page.revisions(prop='ids'))  
last_revision_id = revisions[-1]['revid']
first_revision_id = revisions[0]['revid']
```

Then use the [compare action](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Compare) to compare the revision ids:

```
compare_result = site.get('compare', fromrev=last_revision_id, torev=first_revision_id)
html_diff = compare_result['compare']['*']
```